# How to use del in tuples

Tags: tuples, del

x = 1.0, [2,4,8], 16

4 can be popped out from x[1] by using pop

x[1].pop(1)

but is there anyway this output can be achieved using del?

(1.0, [2, 8], 16)

Comment: `del x[1][1]` ?

Comment: Thank you very much